# browserify 'require' placement

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, browserify

Usually all dependencies are required in the head of the file.

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery');
```

I wonder if it is correct to require in code body. Example: 
`template: require('./home.tpl.hbs'),`

```
module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({

template: require('./home.tpl.hbs'),

render: function () {
...
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to work, but require function is taken from nodejs world (CommonJS modules) and you can read about best practices in its usage [here](http://www.mircozeiss.com/node-js-require-s-best-practices/). So my point is that you need to add local variable at the beggining of the file and then use it wherever you want.